# How to work with AngularJS v1.5+ and angular-ui-router v1.0+ allowing views to be defined as template and controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm migrating from AngularJS v1.5 (not using Components) to AngularJS v1.8, and having angular-ui-router v0.2.0.
After fixing a bunch of errors, my app is not loading. After I saw https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3120#issuecomment-357412768 I then upgraded angular-ui-router to the latest. It's still not working and not throwing any error either.

I've searched a lot to see if I can find a tutorial or guide on how to use angular-ui-router v1.0+ and AngularJS v1.5+ without implementing AngularJS Components but have not found anything.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "angular": "1.5.9" and "angular-ui-router": "1.0.18" works perfectly fine with both components and controllers+templates

Comment: Here's what's shown in browser's console:

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://example.com/content/jscript/1_vendor/AngularJS/Modules/angular-ui-router.js